# Angular view render performance

Tags: angular, performance, ngrx, user-experience

In Angular, which component strategy gives better view render performance?

Parent-Child component(s) that share data via @Input / @Output

**OR**

Independent components that share data via a shared-service/ Ngrx?

Comment: simply, only Two component needs to communicate then you can use `@Input() and @Output()` , and if multiple component needs data changes then you can simple inject service to each component and get latest data to respective component.

Comment: Also, don't forget using the [OnPush](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy]) change detection strategy whenever you can.